# How to multiple rows of a dynamic table to Mysql database with jAutoCalc plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a dynamic table in an  with jAutoCalc plugin to calculate values in each row as well as the total value of all the rows. Can somebody share the code to insertion of each dynamic row to a Mysql database? I am inserting a picture of my table [Demo Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdWvP.jpg)

here in each row the theory and practical marks added automatically; and the subtotal and total also calculated automatically. But I have not been able to send all the rows to Mysql database. The calculation part is done with jAutoCalc plugin.

here is my table format:

```
<table name="cart">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Theory</th>
                    <th>Practical</th>
                    <th>Item Total</th>
                </tr>
                <tr name="line_items">
                    <td><button name="remove">Remove</button></td>
                    <td><select name="subject_name">
                            <option value="Eco">Eco</option>
                            <option value="Eng">Eng</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subject_theory" value="1"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subject_practical" value="9"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subject_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{subject_theory} + {subject_practical}"></td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Subtotal</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" value="" jAutoCalc="SUM({subject_total})"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="grand_total" value="" jAutoCalc="{sub_total}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="99"><button name="add">Add Row</button></td>
                    <td colspan="99"><button name="submit">Submit</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

here is jquery that I used for dynamic generation of rows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                function autoCalcSetup() {
                    $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc('destroy');
                    $('form[name=cart] tr[name=line_items]').jAutoCalc({keyEventsFire: true, decimalPlaces: 0, emptyAsZero: true});
                    $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc({decimalPlaces: 0});
                }
                autoCalcSetup();


                $('button[name=remove]').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var form = $(this).parents('form')
                    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                    autoCalcSetup();

                });

                $('button[name=add]').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var $table = $(this).parents('table');
                    var $top = $table.find('tr[name=line_items]').last();
                    var $new = $top.clone(true);

                    $new.jAutoCalc('destroy');
                    $new.insertAfter($top);
                    $new.find('input[type=text]').val('');
                    autoCalcSetup();

                });

            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Update the post with your input/example data and expected output, the question is not cleared.

Comment: I am inserting a pic of my demo table. Hope it will clear your doubt.

Comment: If you have created a table then share the table structure, or you want to create table as well to store all these values.

Comment: kindly create the dynamic table with auto calculation as well as store those values to database. I have not been able to work this one out.

Comment: Check out the answer posted below might resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have created a table for you with 5 columns as below, the Total field can't be possible as that value is going to calculate on a group of rows. So you can calculate that value while selecting the data from the table as I explained below step-by-step.

So, here all you need to insert the values into, "student_id", "name", "theory", "practical" fields, i.e. 4 fields and 5th column will be calculated by the database itself.

```
mysql> create table mark_obtains(
    -> student_id int,
    -> name varchar(30) not null,
    -> theory int default 0,
    -> practical int default 0,
    -> item_total int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (theory+practical) VIRTUAL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.39 sec)

mysql> insert into mark_obtains(student_id,name,theory,practical) values (1,'asd',5,6);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from mark_obtains;
+------------+------+--------+-----------+------------+
| student_id | name | theory | practical | item_total |
+------------+------+--------+-----------+------------+
|          1 | asd  |      5 |         6 |         11 |
+------------+------+--------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: can you check my question once again? I have added the code format for dynamic creation of tables.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by dynamic table here? What I understand is you have a web page called XYZ and from XYZ want to persist the data into MySQL table. You can simply use the Insert statement and bind the values to them and execute it. if you have many rows on the web page then make a loop inside and then iterate the loop x times where x is the number of rows on web page.

Comment: what I tried to understood is i can add/remove as many rows as i want from the table. In the picture there is an "add row" button which generated the rows and "remove" button in front of every row delete that particular row.

Comment: So, we say the Data Grid element of a web page that holds the data in form of a table, right. Now our data stored in the database in form of a table, so if you want to select the data from table use the "SELECT" and populate select data/rows from the database into the web page tabular form of the element. Now you can edit them delete them or you can add new rows. and finally save to database back. For saving the records again you have to use Insert for all the rows that are added newly, and use the Update for all the rows that updated just now. That's all.

Comment: Yeah I am having problem with the newly added rows.

Comment: Create a flag on a web page and say, added or updated. Then for all the records that you added, directly insert into the table. For those which flag is updated, use the Update statement to modify the DB table data.

Comment: You can mark this questions as answered by right tick.